# Append ajax response to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made a GET request to take all the users and show Name,Surname,Profession and Is_active , this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/see/user",
  success: function(users){
    $user = $("#add_usr");
    $.each(users, function(i, user){
      userArr.push({
        'id': user.id,
        'firstName': user.profile.FirstName,
        'lastName': user.profile.LastName,
        'fullName': user.profile.FirstName + ' ' + user.profile.LastName,
        'profesion': user.profesion,
        'Is_active': user.Is_active

      });
    });
```

and now I want all the professions that users have to append it to my select selector and not to be duplicated , for ex. there are 3 users from my ajax request and the first profession is Plumber second Programmer and third Teacher, and I want these three professions to appear in my select selector because I want to filter users by profesion and I don't now how to start it, thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969754/jquery-append-to-select-with-an-array

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324987/unique-array-by-object-property

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry my mistake

Comment: @freedomn-m can you give me example with the ajax above

Comment: I think you need to use a datatable https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following operations:

- Extract all the professions (e.g. with map)
- Sort them
- Remove duplicates
- Create the select

Heres' how

```js
function extractProfessions(userArr) {
  return userArr
      .map(function(el) {
        return el.profession
      })
      .sort()
      .filter(function(el,i,a) {
        return i==a.indexOf(el);
      });
}
```

You can call this from inside your ajax callback

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/see/user",
  success: function(users){
    $user = $("#add_usr");
    var userArr = []; // YOU DIDN'T HAVE THIS IN YOUR ORIGINAL CODE
    $.each(users, function(i, user){
      userArr.push({
        'id': user.id,
        'firstName': user.profile.FirstName,
        'lastName': user.profile.LastName,
        'fullName': user.profile.FirstName + ' ' + user.profile.LastName,
        'profesion': user.profesion,
        'Is_active': user.Is_active

      });
      var professions = extractProfessions(userArr); // HERE!!!
    });
```

and then add the result to the `select`.

Comment: can you please tell me how to call this , with my example please

Comment: it seems good answer, sorry for my late response, I was very busy, I tried this right now , I added the result like this:`$("#filterByProfession").append('<option>'+ professions +'</option>');` and I have three users, Only one of them has profession , 2 others are null for the moment, and It displays that proferssion 3 times

Comment: I will make this as an accepted answer but i need more help, please

Comment: Sorry, I don't check SO during the weekend. Can you please add an example output from the AJAX call to your question and comment here again when you do?

Comment: Somehow  I solved the problem but its not such perfect, I have 3 selects and one input type number, and I am trying to filter users depend on the value of the selects and input, separately they work fine, but they should be connected , for ex: if i chose age 24 it shows all users from that age, then i chose profesion programmer it it shows users with that profesion but not at age 24, do you understand me

Comment: Yes, I do. But that's a completely different question you should think about a bit and, if you're stuck, ask separetely.

Comment: I can't ask , stackoverflow doesn't let me :(

Comment: Are you getting [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-cant-i-ask-questions-on-stackoverflow)?

Comment: question limit issue

Comment: I asked another question here, can you answer it please, of course if you can [question-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643998/filter-users-by-dropdown?noredirect=1#comment84325840_48643998)

Answer (score 0):

Using what you have, What you can do is have another array and call it `options` to store all the unique ones and then populate your element. By doing this, you select menu will always refresh when you call this ajax request.

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/see/user",
      success: function(users){
        $user = $("#add_usr");
        var options = [];

        $.each(users, function(i, user){
          /* HERE WE CREATE AN OPTIONS LIST FOR THE SELECT*/
          if (-1 != options.indexOf (user.profesion))
            options.push (user.profesion);


          userArr.push({
            'id': user.id,
            'firstName': user.profile.FirstName,
            'lastName': user.profile.LastName,
            'fullName': user.profile.FirstName + ' ' + user.profile.LastName,
            'profesion': user.profesion,
            'Is_active': user.Is_active

          });

          /* HERE WHEN FINISHED YOU CAN POPULATE THE SELECT MENU WITH THESE*/
          $ ('#SELECT_ELEMENT').html (''); // FIRST CLEAR IT

          /* THEN POPULATE IT */
          $.each (options, function (k, v) {
            $ ('#SELECT_ELEMENT').append (v);
          });


        });
```

Comment: this won't duplicate professions, if already exist it should add the same profession twice

Comment: @AgentMike wat? You specifically wrote "and not to be duplicated" in your question.

Comment: You said " I want all the professions that users have to append it to my select selector and not to be duplicated "

Comment: Are you sure you know what you are asking??? if you want the duplicate then just dont do the check `if (-1 != options.indexOf (user.profesion))` Which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @CAllen I think you meant `var options = [];` in you answer.

Comment: right. Thank you. Please change the `var options = {}` to `var options = []` as shown above @Agent Mike

Comment: @AgentMike, regarding your latest comment, at least read what you're pasting in your code instead of spewing error messages you could easily solve yourself.