# Filter users by dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem regarding filtering users with multiple dropdowns , I have 3 dropdowns and one input type number,and I also have 2 switch buttons on or of , and I want all o these to work together, so this is my hmtl

```
<li>
    <label class="switchFilterOn">
        <input class="firstOnOfInput" type="checkbox" checked>
        <span class="sliderOnOrOf round"></span>
    </label>
    <span class="onOfSpan">SHOW ONLY PROJECT MEMBERS:</span>
</li>
<li>
    <label class="switchFilterOn">
        <input class="firstOnOfInput" type="checkbox">
        <span class="sliderOnOrOf round"></span>
    </label>
    <span class="onOfSpan">SHOW INACTIVE EMPLOYEES:</span>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select required="" class="filterSelectOptions" name="filterByProfession" id="filterByProfession">
            <option>PROFESSION</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select required="" class="filterSelectOptions" name="filterByType" id="filterByType">
            <option>TYPE</option>
            <option value="1">INTERNAL</option>
            <option value="2">EXTERNAL</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" min="0" required class="filterSelectOptions" id="filterByAge">
        <small class="ageLabelFilter" for="filterByAge">AGE</small>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select required="" class="filterSelectOptions" name="filterByGender" id="filterByGender">
            <option>GENDER</option>
            <option value="M">MALE</option>
            <option value="F">FEMALE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

I tried this one to filter but it only works separately , So if I filter profession it works fine , but if I want to filter profession Plumber with age 33 and gender male than it doesn't work, they all work separately , this is my code how I filter them

```
var match = function(prof, type,age,gender, profile) {
    var show = (prof === 'PROFESSION' || prof === $(profile).data('profesion') &&
                type === 'TYPE' || type === $(profile).data('type') &&
                age === 'AGE' ||  age === $(profile).data('age') &&
                gender === 'GENDER' || gender === $(profile).data('gender'));

    if (show && !$(profile).is(':visible')) {
        $(profile).fadeIn();
    }

    if (!show && $(profile).is(':visible')) {
        $(profile).fadeOut();
    }
};
var filter = function() {
    var filterByProfession = $('#filterByProfession').val();
    var filterByType = $('#filterByType').val();
    var filterByAge = $('#filterByAge').val();
    var filterByGender = $('#filterByGender').val();

    $('.filterUserBy').each(function(i, profile) {
        match(filterByProfession, filterByType,filterByAge,filterByGender, profile);
    });
};
```

then I call the function on change of each dropdown

```
$('#filterByProfession').change(function () {
        filter();
    });
    //sort users by age
    $('#filterByAge').on("input",function () {
        filter();
    });
    //sort by type.....
    $('#filterByType').change(function () {
        filter();
    });
    //filter by gender......
    $('#filterByGender').change(function () {
        filter();
    });
```

I will really appreciate your help, or maybe different type of solution

Comment: I can tell you why age probably doesn't work, `$.data()` is an expando value. So `age === $(profile).data('age')` is probably '33' === 33, which results in false, try double equal sign in this case because you need type conversion

Comment: yes but that is not the answer, I have already fixed that, I just need a solution all of these to work together

Comment: You can do `$('#filterByGender').change(filter);`, which is actually more efficient

Comment: @Martijn thats ok but they still work separated

Comment: Yes, but not the way you should do it. You now call an anonymous function to call the filterFunction. Just directly call the filter.

Comment: and can you give me some example how to do this, I appreciate you help